# Enriching one Redshift table with time series data from another table using SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have two tables in Redshift. The first (`TABLE1`) is a series of feedback events that can be boiled down the following columns

```
Feedback Datetime | Customer Id | Feedback Score
```

The second (`TABLE2`) is a table that is a time series table that records opt in/out events for a feature

```
Opt Event time | Customer Id | Opt In/Out
```

The last column is (`Opt In/Out`) is either 0 or 1

I want enrich the first table with the opt status of the merchant from the second

So if a Customer had the following timeline

```
T0 -> Opt Out of Feature

T1 -> Opt Into Feature

T2 -> Leave Feedback

T3 -> Opt Out of Feature

T4 -> Leave Feature
```

In the above example `T1 < T2 < T3 < T4`

And the two tables would look like the following

```
TABLE1
Feedback Datetime | Customer Id | Feedback Score
T2                | C1          | S1             
T4                | C1          | S2
```

```
TABLE2
Opt Event time | Customer Id | Opt In/Out
T0             | C1          | 0
T1             | C1          | 1
T3             | C1          | 0
```

After joining and enriching I would want `T1` to be supplemented with the Opt Status from `T2` and look like this

```
Feedback Datetime | Customer Id | Feedback Score | Opt Status
T2                | C1          | S1             | 1
T4                | C1          | S2             | 0
```

The customer IDs are long ints and the Feedback Scores are 1-5. Both date columns are Datetimes

Is there a way to do this join in SQL?